# How can I prevent web crawlers from affecting my cache (Redis, CDN, etc?)

Tags: caching, web-crawler, robots.txt, cache-control

Theory: If a web crawler crawls my entire site, my default caching mechanism (Redis for example) will be swamped, and may age out the wrong data. (depending on the cache policy).

Assuming that web crawlers don't need the performance gains I'm offering to end users, I could edit my app to "protect the cache"

**Question**

- Is this a good idea?
- Do web crawlers measure the time difference between delivered content?
- Aside from user agent, should I "tag" a session that references robots.txt and assume they are a crawler?
- How should I administratively, or programmatically handle this delivery?
- In an extreme example, can I throttle a web crawler?

If I implement this programmatically, I need to tell **GetFromCacheAsync** to not update the cache based on some client information.

- Is it a violation of any domain driven design theory to add a method overload to determine if the cache should be updated?
- Where should I place the logic of "to update Redis" or "don't update Redis" ... this aspect I think is most relevant to DDD

*HomeController.cs*

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Events()
 {
      ViewBag.Events = await eventSvc.GetLiveEvents(DateTime.Now);
     return View();
 }
```

*Services.EventManagementService.cs*

```
public async Task<List<Event>> GetLiveEvents(DateTime currentDate)
{
   //return ctx.Events.Where(e => e.StatusId == (int)EventStatus.Live && e.EventDate >= DateTime.Now).ToList();
  return await cloudCtx.GetLiveEvents(DateTime.Now);
}
```

*Data.CloudContext.cs*

```
    public async Task<List<Event>> GetLiveEvents(DateTime currentDate)
    {
        string year = currentDate.Year.ToString();
        var key = GenerateLiveEventsKey(year); 

        var yearEvents = await cache.GetFromCacheAsync<List<Event>>(key, async () =>
        { 
            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
            string partitionKey = year;

            TableQuery<EventRead> query = new TableQuery<EventRead>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey));
            TableQuerySegment<EventRead> currentSegment = null;
            var result = tableEvents.ExecuteQuery(query);
            while (currentSegment == null || currentSegment.ContinuationToken != null)
            {
                currentSegment = await tableMyEvents.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, currentSegment != null ? currentSegment.ContinuationToken : null);
                foreach (EventRead nosqlEvent in currentSegment.Results)
                {
                    var eventObj = nosqlEvent.ToEvent(true);
                    events.Add(eventObj);
                }
            }

            return events;
        });
        return yearEvents.Where(e => e.EventDate >= currentDate).ToList();
    }
```

*Data.Cache.cs*

```
  public async Task<T> GetFromCacheAsync<T>(string key, Func<Task<T>> missedCacheCall, TimeSpan timeToLive)
    {
        if (!IsCacheAvailable)
        {
            var ret = await missedCacheCall();
            return ret;
        }

        IDatabase cache = Connection.GetDatabase();
        var obj = await cache.GetAsync<T>(key);
        if (obj == null)
        {
            obj = await missedCacheCall();
            if (obj != null)
            {
                cache.Set(key, obj);
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Is this a good idea?
```

Don't fix it if it is not broken (or if there is no real issue in the first place).

```
Do web crawlers measure the time difference between delivered content?
```

Google does. Its bots will slow down the crawling if necessary.

```
Aside from user agent, should I "tag" a session that references
robots.txt and assume they are a crawler?
```

User agent is good enough.

```
How should I administratively, or programmatically handle this delivery?
```

Return a 503 to tell bots they are coming too often.

```
In an extreme example, can I throttle a web crawler?
```

Yes, see above.